# Calculating R1 and RFOD for BQ51050B

Tags: integrated-circuit, wireless, charging

So iam building a wireless charging receiver circuit.One of the options i need to use is setting a overcurrent protection is solving for RILIM.I can achieve this by solving equation 1 http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51050b.pdf#20 to find R1 resistance values and place the resistors following the schematic in the pdf.The problem iam facing is when i solve for R1 is i dont see a way to solve for RFOD or can find a standard value to use for calculation.If anyone can point me in the right direction it would appreciated thanks.
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51050b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used the bq51050b in a commercial project.  In section 9.2.1.2.3, Charging and Termination Current (on page 30), it says "Setting R\$_{FOD}\$ to 200 Ω as a starting point before the FOD calibration is recommended."  And then solving for R\$_{1}\$ using the equations in section 8.3.4.3, Battery Charge Current Setting Calculations on page 20.

So that's what I did, and ended up just using the 200 Ω value.  That is also the value that TI uses on their [evaluation board](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluua25c/sluua25c.pdf) for the charger (labeled R2 on page 3 of that PDF).